# How to execute an sh file from a short cut in the desktop to run an app

Tags: icons

I see so many answers but nothing like I'm looking for. I have this sh file that is to run an app (TunerStudio.sh) that I can run in terminal mode ( ./TunerStudio.sh) with out any problem, but I like to run it from the desktop short cut or an icon.

Thanks
Miguel

Comment: What happens when you click on the desktop shortcut? Do you get an error message? How did you create the desktop shortcut?

Comment: I don't have any desktop shortcut right now. I have to run it in terminal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a shortcut on the desktop, open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) then type:

```
cd Desktop
ln -s ../TunerStudio.sh TunerStudio
```

Comment: When I do that it will open the sh file in edit mode

Comment: When nautilus (a.k.a. files) is active use the dropdown on the very top of the screen (next to activities), then select preferences and under behavior you can choose what is to be done with executable files (display, run, or ask).

Comment: perfect, it worked, u r the best

Comment: Glad to hear. Then you should accept my answer by setting the checkmark on the left.